# Consider $c_{00}$ as a subspace of $(\ell^p,\|\cdot\|_p)$. Show that the closure of $(c_{00},\|\cdot\|_1)$ is $\ell^1$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider $c_{00}$ as a subspace of $(\ell^p,\|\cdot\|_p)$. Show that the closure of $(c_{00},\|\cdot\|_1)$ is $\ell^1$, closure of $(c_{00},\|\cdot\|_2)$ is $\ell^2$ and  closure of $(c_{00},\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is $c_0$.

$$c_{00}=\{x=(x(1),x(2),\ldots): x(j)=0\ \forall j \ge j_x, \exists j_x \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

So I create  a set of sequences like this:
$$
\begin{align}
x_1 & =(x(1),0,0,0,\ldots) \\
x_2 & =(x(1),x(2),0,0,\ldots) \\
& \,\,\,\vdots \\
x_n & =(x(1),x(2),\ldots,x(n),0,0,\ldots)
\end{align}
$$
where the $$x=(x(1),x(2),\ldots,x(n),\ldots)$$ is the parent sequence which I pick in the various spaces. 
I think that these sequences will do the work for me.

For (a)  $(c_{00},\|\cdot\|_\infty)$

let $$x=(x(1),x(2),\ldots,x(n),\ldots) \in c_0$$
So for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x(n)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $n \ge n_0$. Now for all $n \ge n_0$ , $$\|x_n-x\|_\infty=\sup\{|x(m)|, m > n_0\} \le \frac{\varepsilon}{2} < \varepsilon$$

for (b) , $(c_{00},\|\cdot\|_p)$

let $$x=(x(1),x(2),\ldots,x(n),\ldots) \in \ell^p$$
Now $$\|x_n-x\|_p=\left(\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty|x_i|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

Now since $x \in \ell^p$, the series $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} < \infty$$ and hence the tail of the series goes to $0$. Thus there is a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge n_0$ $$\left(\sum_{i=n}^\infty |x_i|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} < \epsilon $$

And we are done. 
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Hint: What is $\|x_n - x\|_{p}$?

Comment: @NateEldredge .. Thank you. Is this what you meant??

Comment: Yes!  By the way, in the $l^\infty$ case you are not quite done.  You have only shown that $c_0$ is contained in the closure of $c_{00}$.  To show the opposite inclusion, show that $c_0$ is closed in $l^\infty$.